# How to subtract the sum of columns from different tables?

Tags: postgresql, view

I have two tables:

1. Withdrawals: `account_id` + `amount`
2. Prizes: `account_id` + `amount`

I want to calculate a balance per `account`, probably in a `VIEW`.

I could have two queries:

```
SELECT account_id, SUM(amount) FROM prizes GROUP BY account_id
```

which gives me the total prize per account, and:

```
SELECT account_id, SUM(amount) FROM withdrawals GROUP BY account_id
```

which gives me all withdrawals for these accounts.

Now, I'd like to subtract them to return balances for my accounts. What is the most efficient way to create a view like that?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f9bf40

Comment: Hey Kamil, thanks for the question and the fiddle. It looks like sqlfiddle is temporarily down, though, and your test setup is therefore inaccessible at the moment. Could you please provide another one using any of the alternatives [listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37646270)? Thanks again and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can full join the grouped results and build the difference of the sums.

```
CREATE VIEW balance
AS
SELECT coalesce(x.account_id, y.account_id) account_id,
       coalesce(x.amount, 0) - coalesce(y.amount, 0) amount
       FROM (SELECT account_id,
                    sum(amount) amount
                    FROM prizes
                    GROUP BY account_id) x
            FULL JOIN (SELECT account_id,
                              sum(amount) amount
                              FROM withdrawals
                              GROUP BY account_id) y
                      ON x.account_id = y.account_id;
```

---

Edit:

If you also want a balance of 0 for accounts without prizes or withdrawals, left join the subqueries to the accounts.

```
CREATE VIEW balance
            SELECT a.id account_id,
                   coalesce(x.amount, 0) - coalesce(y.amount, 0) amount
                   FROM accounts a
                        LEFT JOIN (SELECT account_id,
                                          sum(amount) amount
                                          FROM prizes
                                          GROUP BY account_id) x
                                  ON x.account_id = a.id
                        LEFT JOIN (SELECT account_id,
                                          sum(amount) amount
                                          FROM withdrawals
                                          GROUP BY account_id) y
                                  ON y.account_id = a.id;
```

Comment: And how can I return `accounts` with `balance` of `0` if they have no `prizes` neither `withdrawals`?

Comment: @KamilLelonek: Then you have to left join the balances to a table storing all accounts. Unfortunately you didn't reveal any information about such a table here. Maybe it's in the fiddle, but this is still down. (Tip: A fiddle is a real nice thing to provide. But always post a copy of the relevant commands in a question. That helps, if the fiddle is down and/or if someone wants to set up an test environment on their own server.)

Comment: Here it is: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ruYY46GPGvwMTuDvLrxxzF/0

Comment: @KamilLelonek: See my edit.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to a full join, you could use `UNION ALL` to combine the two aggregated sets together, only the `withdrawals` set would be included with the negated results. You would then use the combined set as a derived table and aggregate the amounts per `account_id` once more:

```
SELECT
  account_id,
  SUM(amount) AS balance
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      account_id,
      SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM
      prizes
    GROUP BY
      account_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
      account_id,
      -SUM(amount) AS amount
    FROM
      withdrawals
    GROUP BY
      account_id
  ) AS derived
GROUP BY
  account_id
;
```

I am not sure how this query would compare to the full join solution but it looks simple enough to me to qualify as a good starting point.